# Having two button in a list view in javaFX with XML file

Tags: java, xml, listview, button, javafx

I'm trying to make an application like Facebook with javaFX, and I want to have a page to show friends in a list view with option confirm and remove friends request. I was thinking to use list view but I don't know how to add buttons on each cell. 
So, is it possible to add two buttons of friends request or remove in a list view in JavaFX
like facebook friends list 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF43B.jpg)

If there are other control views that It does the same thing please let me know.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way, that I think is pretty simple, is to just provide your own `CellFactory` for the `ListView`. This allows you to build an entire layout for each cell.

The following sample application will demonstrate the process:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class ListViewButtonsSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Create some sample Users
        ObservableList<User> usersList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        usersList.addAll(
                new User("Amir"),
                new User("Jasmine"),
                new User("Leonardo")
        );

        // Create the ListView
        ListView<User> listView = new ListView<>();

        // We need to create a new CellFactory so we can display our layout for each individual user
        listView.setCellFactory((Callback<ListView<User>, ListCell<User>>) param -> {
            return new ListCell<User>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(User user, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(user, empty);

                    if (user == null || empty) {
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        // Here we can build the layout we want for each ListCell. Let's use a HBox as our root.
                        HBox root = new HBox(10);
                        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
                        root.setPadding(new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10));

                        // Within the root, we'll show the username on the left and our two buttons to the right
                        root.getChildren().add(new Label(user.getUsername()));

                        // I'll add another Region here to expand, pushing the buttons to the right
                        Region region = new Region();
                        HBox.setHgrow(region, Priority.ALWAYS);
                        root.getChildren().add(region);

                        // Now for our buttons
                        Button btnAddFriend = new Button("Add Friend");
                        btnAddFriend.setOnAction(event -> {
                            // Code to add friend
                            System.out.println("Added " + user.getUsername() + " as a friend!");
                        });
                        Button btnRemove = new Button("Remove");
                        btnRemove.setOnAction(event -> {
                            // Code to remove friend
                            System.out.println("Broke up with " + user.getUsername() + "!");
                        });
                        root.getChildren().addAll(btnAddFriend, btnRemove);

                        // Finally, set our cell to display the root HBox
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(root);
                    }

                }
            };

        });

        // Set our users to display in the ListView
        listView.setItems(usersList);

        root.getChildren().add(listView);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(500);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

class User {

    private final StringProperty username = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public User(String username) {
        this.username.set(username);
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username.get();
    }

    public StringProperty usernameProperty() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username.set(username);
    }
}
```

---

> **The Result:**

[image: screenshot]

> **Note:** The result is similar to Sedrick's solution, but does not use FXML. If you intend to use this `ListCell` implementation elsewhere in your application, you would want to create a separate class for this particular `ListCell` so it can be reused.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (rough) demo app using `FXML`. The key is creating a custom node to be the view of the `ListViewCell`.

> Custom node for the `ListViewCell`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<fx:root fx:id="hboxRoot" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.0" type="HBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <VBox AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
               <children>
                  <Label fx:id="lblName" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Label" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                  <Label fx:id="lblAge" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Label" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                  <Label fx:id="lblSex" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Label" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="20.0" />
               </padding>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="10.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="btnAdd" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
            <Button fx:id="btnRemove" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

> Custom node `Controller`. **When dealing with custom nodes, I am not sure if this is called a `Controller`. It works similar to a `Controller.**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class CustomCellView extends HBox
{
    @FXML
    HBox hboxRoot;
    @FXML
    Label lblName, lblAge, lblSex;
    @FXML
    Button btnAdd, btnRemove;

    public CustomCellView()
    {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CellView.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    HBox getHBoxRoot()
    {
        return hboxRoot;
    }

    void setlblNameText(String text)
    {
        lblName.setText(text);
    }

    void setlblAgeText(String text)
    {
        lblAge.setText(text);
    }

    void setlblSexText(String text)
    {
        lblSex.setText(text);
    }

    void setBtnAddAction(EventHandler actionEvent)
    {
        btnAdd.setOnAction(actionEvent);
    }

    void setBtnRemoveAction(EventHandler actionEvent)
    {
        btnRemove.setOnAction(actionEvent);
    }
}
```

> ListViewCell

```
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;

public class ListViewCell extends ListCell<Person>
{
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(person, empty);
        if (person != null) {
            CustomCellView customCellView = new CustomCellView();
            customCellView.setlblNameText(person.getName());
            customCellView.setlblAgeText(person.getAge());
            customCellView.setlblSexText(person.getSex());

            EventHandler addHandler = (EventHandler) (Event event) -> {
                System.out.println("Add " + person.getName());
            };
            customCellView.setBtnAddAction(addHandler);

            EventHandler removeHandler = (EventHandler) (Event event) -> {
                System.out.println("Remove " + person.getName());
            };
            customCellView.setBtnRemoveAction(removeHandler);

            setGraphic(customCellView.getHBoxRoot());
        }
    }
}
```

> Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication311 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> Main FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="573.0" prefWidth="726.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" fx:controller="javafxapplication311.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <ListView fx:id="lvMain" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

> Main FXMLController

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    private ListView lvMain;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        lvMain.getItems().add(new Person("John Doe", "22", "Male"));
        lvMain.getItems().add(new Person("Jane Doe", "21", "Female"));

        lvMain.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public ListCell call(ListView param)
            {
                return new ListViewCell();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

> Person

```
/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String sex;

    public Person(String name, String age, String sex)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public String getSex()
    {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex)
    {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }


}
```

[image]