# How to bind a DoubleProperty to the difference of two other DoubleProperty in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I have a ListView with custom cells : these cells are made of a label and a delete button.

I want the PreferedWidthProperty of the Label to be constantly equal to the width of the ListView minus the width of the button.

Hence, in the updateItem of the custom cell class, I added the following code :

```
label.prefWidthProperty().bind(listViewWidth.subtract(delButton.widthProperty()));
```

But with this, the width of the Button is not substracted and the width of the label is equal to the width of the ListView : a horizontal scroll bar appears and the button is out of the frame.

After a bit of testing, it appears the width of the button is equal to zero at the moment this code is executed (since the button itself is not shown yet) but it is never recalculated : it always stays zero, hence the substration is always equal to the ListView's unmodified width.

How to force the binding to be constantly equal to the substraction of the current values of these objects?

Edit :
What I want is this extremely simple look :
[image]

That is :

- Each line is composed of a label and a button
- The Button is at the end of the line
- The text goes up to the button and wraps, no horizontal scrollbar.

And what I get is that :
[image]

The text wraps alright.... but the Label has the width of the ListView so the button is out of the frame and needs to be scrolled to to delete the line, which looks kind of ridiculous.

My factory is very simple :

```
fx_listBoxMain.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>()
{
    @Override
    public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param)
    {
    DeletableCell result = null;
    try
    {
        result = new DeletableCell();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        //Deal with that case as soon as the basics are working
    }
    return result;
    }
});
```

The "DeletableCell" is inflated from the following fxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<HBox fx:controller="DeletableCellController"  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
    <Label fx:id="fx_labelView" wrapText="true"/>
    <Button fx:id="fx_delButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="X" onAction="#deleteAction" />
    </children>
</HBox>
```

So it is a very straightforward HBox with a Label and a Button and I want the Label to have the width of the containing listview minus the width of the button.

I need to set the PreferedWidth property because without that, the text will not wrap and I will have something even uglier : labels of only one long line with a huge horizontal scrollbar. So I looked around SO to find how not to have that and found out you needed to set PreferedWidth because wrapText="true" is not sufficient for that.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you shouldn't need to use binding here at all. Use a layout pane for your custom cells that handles this for you. What is your end goal here? Can you post a screenshot of what you're trying to accomplish? Also, please add the code for your custom cell factory.

Comment: Note that the size of the `ListView` includes things like the vertical scrollbar. Furthermore there are is a margin around the graphic of the cell...

Comment: @fabian you're of course right, but it is not difficult to add a few pixels to the substraction to take that into account. I'm not bothering you with the minute polishing : my problem is about how to take the button into account, after that I'll polish away on my own.

Comment: Will your `Button` have a variable width? Generall, it's width won't grow unless you instruct it to.

Comment: Seems like `HBox.setHgrow(label, Priority.ALWAYS);` or the FXML equivalentshould work.

Comment: Setting the `maxWidth` property of the `HBox` (not `Label`) seems to accomplish your goal for me: `maxWidthProperty().bind(listView.widthProperty().subtract(button.widthProperty()));` [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/GQv7bdh)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602086/having-two-button-in-a-list-view-in-javafx-with-xml-file/53603273#53603273

Comment: @Sedrick that doesn't work : the text won't wrap with that.

Comment: @YkonO'Clast thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `MaxWidthProperty` of the cell's `HBox` should accomplish this. We would bind that value to the width of the `ListView` minus the width the `ListView` padding:

```
maxWidthProperty().bind(listView.widthProperty().subtract(25));
```

Here is a quick sample program that demonstrates it. This does build the custom `ListCell` in Java (instead of FXML), but the general idea would be the same.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListCellWrap extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();

        // Sample data
        listView.getItems().addAll(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        );

        // Override the ListCell
        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<String>() {

            // Create our cell's layout
            final Label label = new Label() {{
                setWrapText(true);
            }};
            final Button button = new Button("X") {{
                setOnAction(event -> {
                    // Processing here
                });
            }};

            final HBox root = new HBox(5, label, button) {{
                maxWidthProperty().bind(listView.widthProperty().subtract(25));
            }};

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    label.setText(item);
                    setGraphic(root);
                }
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(listView);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**The Result:**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: THis does work, I am a bit surprised that text wraps (since in my preceding attempts it never would if PreferedWidthProperty was not set on the label). There is a bit of magic in the way JavaFX handles all this, I need to study it more. Thanks for your help in any case!

Comment: In actuality, binding the the width of the `Button` is unnecessary. Instead, you can just call `.subtract(25)` in your binding. You just need to account for the padding and such of the `ListView`. I'm not sure what the exact amount of padding is, but that's all you really need. You might need to account for the scrollbars, though, when they become visible, and update the binding.